# argument of type 'StringVar' is not iterable problem when creating and packing multiple widgets

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When creating a flashcard project I ran into the error argument of type 'StringVar' is not iterable in this code:

```
    for i in res:
        with open(f"flashdata/{res[e]}", "r") as f:
            g = []
            f.seek(0)
            g = StringVar(tp, f.read().splitlines())
            tplist = Listbox(tp, g)
            tplist.pack()
            e += 1
            f.close()
```

It's meant to put lines from a text file into a list, convert to `StringVar`, and then create widgets and `pack()` them for as many text files as there are in `flashdata/`. It creates the list just fine, however it springs an error whenever I try to convert it to a `StringVar`. Here's the full error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/shonky/Desktop/Python Programs/Flashcard Studio/(m) prgmctk copy 2.py", line 25, in review_button
    tplist = Listbox(tp, g)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 3191, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'listbox', cnf, kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2595, in __init__
    BaseWidget._setup(self, master, cnf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2566, in _setup
    if 'name' in cnf:
TypeError: argument of type 'StringVar' is not iterable
```

And here's the full code:

```
import requests
from html import unescape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
from tkinter import *
import os

def review_button():
    tp = Toplevel()
    tp.title("Flashcard_Studio/Sets")
    tp.minsize(200,200)
    tp.maxsize(200,200)
    e = 0
    c = 0
    res = []
    for path in os.listdir("flashdata/"):
        c += 1
        res.append(path)
    for i in res:
        with open(f"flashdata/{res[e]}", "r") as f:
            #for num in f: pass
            g = []
            f.seek(0)
            g = StringVar(tp, f.read().splitlines())
            #g = StringVar(tp, g)
            tplist = Listbox(tp, g)
            tplist.pack()
            e += 1
            f.close()
    label2 = Label(tp, text = "Sets:")
    label2.pack()

def scrape():
    flshlinelen = 0
    print("Button pressed")
    HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36"
    }
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(entry_text.get(), headers=HEADERS).text, "html.parser")
    flashcard_title = soup.find("h1").text

    f = open(f'flashdata/{flashcard_title}.txt', 'w')

    flsh = soup.find_all("div", class_ = "SetPageTerms-term")
    flsh += soup.find_all("div", class_ = "SetPageTerms-term SetPageTerms-term--beyondSignupThreshold")

    for index, flashcards in enumerate(flsh):
        flshlst = flsh[index]
        flash1 = flshlst.find("a", class_ = "SetPageTerm-wordText").text
        flash2 = flshlst.find("a", class_ = "SetPageTerm-definitionText").text
        with open(f"flashdata/{flashcard_title}.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(f"w: {flash1}\n")
            f.write(f"def: {flash2}\n")
            flshlinelen += 2
            print(f"w: {flash1}\n")
            print(f"def: {flash2}\n")
    opener = open("flashdata/" + flashcard_title + ".txt", "a")
    opener.write(str(flshlinelen))
    print(flshlinelen)
    opener.close()
    f.close()
    x = open(f"flashdata/{flashcard_title}.txt", "r")
    print(x.read())

root = Tk()

root.title("Flashcard_Studio/Scrape")
root.minsize(700,100)
root.maxsize(700,100)

label = Label(text = "Quizlet Link:")
entry_text = StringVar()
entry = Entry(textvariable = entry_text, width = 75)
button1 = Button(text = "Get Flashcards", command = scrape)
button2 = Button(root, text = "Review Sets", command = review_button)
label.pack()
entry.pack()
button1.pack()
button2.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the actual error.

Comment: @BryanOakley Have done so, completely forgot initially as I was in a rush. thanks!

Comment: What do you think passing an instance of `StringVar` as the second argument of `Listbox(tp, g)` is supposed to do?

Comment: @BryanOakley It was just some earlier code I forgot to delete and commented out instead.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. You're still passing an instance of `StringVar` as a positional parameter to `Listbox`. What do you think `Listbox` will do with that variable? Have you found some documentation somewhere that says you can do that?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yup, it was a small error, figured it out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `Listbox` to take in the information of `g`, it has to be under the `listvariable` parameter.
In practice:

```
    for i in res:
        with open(f"flashdata/{res[e]}", "r") as f:
            g = []
            f.seek(0)
            g = f.read().splitlines()
            g = StringVar(tp, g)
            tplist = Listbox(tp, listvariable = g)
            tplist.pack()
            e += 1
            f.close()
```